# Arrange multiple graphics inside a subfloat

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm using the `subfig` package to arrange multiple graphics inside a figure. I'm trying to arrange two graphics vertically inside a subfloat but keep getting an error. I'd like the figures to be arranged something like this:

```
 _____   _____
|_____| |     |
 _____  |     |
|_____| |_____|
  (a)     (b)
```

But when I try

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][]{
    \includegraphics{graph1} \\
    \includegraphics{graph2}
}
\subfloat[][]{
    \includegraphics{graph3}
}
\end{figure}
```

I get the error `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`. If I remove the linebreak inside the subfloat the error goes away but then my figures aren't arranged right.  How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one option using the `subfigure` environment from the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package and taking advantage of the optional arguments for the environment (the same as those for a `minipage`);  depending on the actual size of your images, you might need to adjust some lengths:
:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b][6.5cm][b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{smallfigure1}\\\vfill
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{smallfigure2}
\caption{Two small subfigures}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b][6.5cm][b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{largefigure}
\caption{A large subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{three subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

And here's an option using the `subfig` package and some `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Two small subfigures]{%
\begin{minipage}[b][6.5cm][t]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{smallfigure1}

\vfill
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{smallfigure2}
\end{minipage}}%
\subfloat[A larger subfigure]{\begin{minipage}[b][6.5cm][t]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6.5cm]{largefigure}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{three subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can box the larger image and measure its height to use this value for the minipages height. The mechanism is explained in [Aligning 3 images square in a box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114332/aligning-3-images-square-in-a-box)

Comment: Is there any way to do this with `subfig`?

Comment: @DavidP Sure! Please see my updated answer.